# Can a particle stop disintegrating by zeno effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Can a free neutron be prevented from disintegrating by observing it continuously? (Zeno effect).

Comment: Related: [Isn't the detector always measuring, and thus always collapsing the state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/504493) and [What happens when we constantly observe a neutron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335743)